# Can more than one person work at the same time in Packet Tracer?

Tags: cisco, network, packet-tracer

I want to know if more of one person can work in packete tracer at the same time. For example if a friend from her house and I from mine could work in the same proyect of packet tracer at the same time and when we add or creat something new that thing appears in the packet tracer of the other person.

Comment: That is not how it works. It is a tool for a person to use to study for the CCNA exams, not a multiuser application.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no.

Packet Tracer is not designed in that way.